# What roles do these parts play in the following sentences?

Tags: sentence-structure

What roles/elements/components (e.g. subject, ...) of a sentence do the parts in bold play in the following sentences? I am asking about the terminology of the components of a sentence.

> I was doubtful **of my judgment**.
>
> There is no/a doubt **whether our men are conquering**.
>
> It is doubtful **whether our men are conquering**.

Comment: We don't say [*There is no doubt whether...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There+is+no+doubt+that%2CThere+is+no+doubt+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Also note that ***to conquer*** is rarely used intransitively, so it's *There is no doubt **that** we are **winning***. But apart from minor errors like that, the bold elements look like *complements* to me. What did you think they were?